# Selecting a particular item in Combobox in window 8 app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I have a variable which contains a value such as

-9

i have 21 items in the combo box and their contents set to from -10 to +10.

i want to programmatically select the combobox item based on the variable...

i been looking for some sort of reference or solution but cannot find one...

```
myVar = "-9";
myCB.selectedValue = myVar.ToString();
```

the above code doesn't give any error but the combobox displays with a blank value... all other values are there (-10 to +10) but none of them are selected....

sorry if the question is too stupid.... but i am learning to code for windows 8 apps using c#

please help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 21 items in you combobox are selectable by using the indexes of 0 to 20. Your code above shows you are trying to set the value to -9 which does not exist and you are trying to set it with a string of -9 (will fail unless the value is -9 and you use SelectedItem). You should really be using SelectedIndex or SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue.

Put some smarts in your code before setting combobox. eg -9 would be 1. Hope this helps!

Comment: `myVar = 10 + myVar; myCB.selectedIndex = myVar;`
 Sorted my issue... thanks for giving me an idea...

Answer (score 1):

Are you possibly looking for Combobox.SelectedItem?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx

(This is assuming you've bound your Combobox directly to string objects; so give

```
myCB.SelectedItem = "-9";
```

a go)

Comment: i have tried
    myCB.SeletedItem = "-9";
and the combobox is blank